# Make object that encapsulates List<> accessable via [] operator?

Tags: c#, list, encapsulation

I have a class that I made that is basically an encapsulated `List<>` for a certain type. I can access the List items by using `[]` like if it was an array, but I don't know how to make my new class inherit that ability from `List<>`. I tried searching for this but I'm pretty sure I don't know how to word correctly what I want to do and found nothing useful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's called an [**indexer**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx):

```
public SomeType this[int index] {
    get { }
    set { }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's called an **[indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx)**.

> Indexers allow instances of a class or struct to be indexed just like
>   arrays. Indexers resemble properties except that their accessors take
>   parameters.

- Indexers enable objects to be indexed in a similar manner to arrays.
- A `get` accessor returns a value. A `set` accessor assigns a value.
- The `this` keyword is used to define the indexers.
- The `value` keyword is used to define the value being assigned by the set indexer.

Here is an **[EXAMPLE](http://ideone.com/fzgCY2)**.

Answer (score 1):

List already have a definition for the Indexer so there is no need to change that code. It will work by default.

```
   public class MyClass : List<int>
   {

   }
```

And we can access the indexer here. Even though we havent implemented anything

```
MyClass myclass = new MyClass();
myclass.Add(1);
int i = myclass[0]; //Fetching the first value in our list ( 1 )
```

*Note that the List class isn't designed to be inherited. You should be encapsulating it, not extending it. – **Servy***

And this would look something like

```
public class MyClass 
{
    private List<int> _InternalList = new List<int>();

    public int this[int i]
    {
        get { return _InternalList[i]; }
        set { _InternalList[i] = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the `List` class isn't designed to be inherited.  You should be encapsulating it, not extending it.

Comment: I just fixed my title, I recognize it wasn't quite correct and it was also somewhat contradicting with my post. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Servy Thanks for that. Added it with the solution.